# How to add field 'regular price' and 'sku' of WooCommerce product in title and description with Yoast SEO plugin?

Tags: wordpress, seo, woocommerce

How to add field 'regular price' and 'sku' of WooCommerce product in title and description with Yoast SEO plugin? Tried with custom fields but not working. All fields that I need are here: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I find out how can I do this. At first, I found needed key (value in meta_key) at wp_postmeta table. The result is %%cf__price%% (the key was "__price").

Comment: Working fine. for sku use `%%cf__sku%%`.